# Where's the equivalent site for topics outside of computer science?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions that aren’t programming questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions)

Quite a day never goes by where I don't marvel at the wonders that is the Stack Overflow trilogy of sites. Its superiority over other forum systems in dealing with questions and answers leaves me positively agape.

As such, spoiled by the experience, I meet the old chap, Frustration, when asking questions on more mainstream topics on the basic forum software.

Where can one turn toward to ask questions that do not fit the fields covered by Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User?

Comment: @random: Are you high?

Comment: This would have been handy on the notification. But, no. @bal

Answer (score 2):

There are [plenty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites).

Answer (score 0):

Loads of [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) sites out there.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sites using same engine as StackOverflow:

- ServerFault.com
- SuperUser.com
- StartUps.com

But a site isn't built just with an good engine; most important thing are people. And to check if there are good people using a site, you'll need to spend some time in there.